# Split a string about all dot characters(.) except urls and email addresses in Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I am a relative newbie to regular expressions. I have a very simple use case in Python but I'm not able to figure the easiest way to do it. I have a paragraph which I want to split into sentences. Its a technical paragraph explaining certain steps, so I am using a very simple thing for now, which is splitting about all the dots(.) 
However, the paragraph may also have some URLs or email addresses which may contain a dot (.) but I do not want to split them up. One way is to take out all the URLs and email addresses from the paragraph (using regex?) then split is about (.) and then add back the URLs etc. 
I'm assuming there must be a better way to achieve this in one go by using the split function from the regex library with the appropriate regular expression.
Providing an example to be clear:

```
input= "Click on the next button. If you do not see this option, you may contact: xyz@support.com. Please mention your user id in the email"
output= ["click on the next button", "If you do not see this option, you may contact: xyz@support.com", "Please mention your user id in the email"]
```

Comment: for given example, using `.` followed by space would work..

Answer (score 1):

```
outp = inp.split('. ') #Will not trigger on URLS and email adresses
```

Assuming no grammar faults in the paragraph.

Comment: Not sure how valid an assumption is that. I could try this as a last resort, but if there's a method that doesn't take this assumption, I'd prefer that.

Comment: @ShubhamAtreja in that case, adding better sample input to question would help... it is difficult for those answering to guess what all cases your input could have..

Answer (score 0):

```
\.\s*(?=[A-Z])
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/AayT6H/1